# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to retreive data from a Future < String > type but i am getting this exception :

```
Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'
```

this is the method that returns a Future < String > :

```
 class  EtablissementController{

  Future<String> AfficherEtablissement() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/getetab');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  }
}
```

and here i am calling this method and populating the data returned :

```
    etabController = EtablissementController() ;
    //fetching data
  etabController.AfficherEtablissement().then((value) => {
    print("Fetched values: "+value)
  }) ;
    //fetching data
```

Comment: btw, regarding method names [link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#do-name-other-identifiers-using-lowercamelcase) says `DO name other identifiers using lowerCamelCase.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're **returning a different type data** via this

```
// this is a json decoded data, not String
return json.decode(response.body);
```

and mentioned the **return data type String in your Generic Data type for you Future**

```
Future<String> AfficherEtablissement() async {}
```

Try, declaring the right data type for your method `AfficherEtablissement()`.

**Suggestion:** Use your method name as a `camelCase`. Good dart practice, you can read more about dart guides here : [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart)

```
  // return the dynamic data type
  Future<dynamic> AfficherEtablissement() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/getetab');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  }
```

And when you fetch the data or print the data, you must change it to String, via `toString()`, since you get the dynamic data type, but in print, it requires `String`

```
etabController.AfficherEtablissement().then((value) => {
  print("Fetched values: "+value.toString());
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , i just tried the method you suggested and i am still getting the same exception

Comment: Now you must be getting the error while doing this: `print("Fetched values: "+value)`. Try doing this `print("Fetched values: "+value.toString())`. Rest will be same, and let me know @CoderTn

Comment: Thank you sir! All the best @CoderTn :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are getting in response, but you can do `typecast`

```
 Future<String> AfficherEtablissement() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/getetab');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body) as String; // it should return String response. 
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  }
```

Comment: @CoderTn: what was the actual issue, is it returning String?